# Linux - FTP script to download file (wildcard in directory name)

Tags: bash, ftp

I am trying to create an FTP script to automatic download (using CRON) 1 file daily.

The directory and file names are dates with random numbers at the end. For example:

20201014-RandomNumberHere

So I need to create a script that get current date and set it to a variable and adds a wildcard at the end. For example:

```
variable = "$ (date +"%Y%m%d")"
```

The script would be something like this:

```
wget ftp://user:pass@ftp.server.com/variable*/variable*.GBK
```

How do I use wildcard with FTP?

Comment: wget "ftp://user:pass@ftp.server.com/$variable*/$variable*.GBK"

Comment: This might help: [How to automatically download a specific file type from within a wildcard folder on an FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47143810/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus I need in Linux.

Comment: @RamanSailopal didn't work. The server does not interpret "*" as a wildcard. The error: "The directory 20201014 *" was not found.

Comment: OK try - wget "user:pass@ftp.server.com/$variable"*"/$variable"*".GBK"

Comment: Error: "The directory 20201014" was not found.

Comment: wget "user:pass@ftp.server.com/$variable"\*"/$variable"\*".GBK"

Comment: Apologies, the last comment stripped the \*

Comment: Error: "The directory 20201014*" was not found.

Comment: `variable = "$ (date +"%Y%m%d")"` ? Surely you mean `variable="$ (date +"%Y%m%d")"` . (please update your Q, rather than replying on comments). Good luck.

Comment: idk why they closed the topic... its not the same question of "Wildcard in bash script".